# Hypothesis testing - Neyman-Pearson Lemma

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

While studying for my exam and practicing with old exams I came across this question. In the answer to part d) they mention that both coefficients are positive and hence for some c the test in part b) is MP.

I do not understand why this is true? Do they mean that if X and Y equal 1 the left hand side of the inequality is postive and so you can find some positive c (even if c is really small like 0,001) such that this inequality holds?

The exam question:
[image: Question Exam]

The answer:
[image: Answer Exam]